# how do I initialise an array of pointers to int?

Tags: arrays, pointers, initialization

this is annoying me....

Can anybody let me know how to initialise so I can call the function
below with parameters.

// arr is typedef'ed to an array on integers

```
typedef int arr[];
```

// arr_ptr is a pointer to an array of integers

```
typedef arr *arr_ptr;
```

// two parameters, A & B are pointers to array
// of integers and N the size of both the arrays

```
void F(arr_ptr A, arr_ptr B, size_t N)
{
    // array of pointers to int
}
```

How do I call F with parameters? N is obviously the length of A & B's array but I cant get a function call compiling ok.

Comment: You should mention which programming language your question is about.

Comment: Assumed C++, will do next time. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

try

```
typedef *arr_ptr[arr.size()];
```

this should create an array of pointers

Comment: Thanks ! Umm...can't see where I mark this  as answered so you get your credits. Where do I do that.